# My break code on my Pomodoro isn't switching correctly. What is the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On my HTML/CSS/JS page, I'm writing a *Pomodoro Timer*. I sped up the length of the code for debugging but when it's done with **session**, it should switch to **break** and start a new timer. Instead, it says **break**, except the timer, is at **0:00**. Here's my code:

```js
let sessionLength = $("#session-length").text() * 1;
let breakLength = $("#session-length").text() * 1;
let seconds = sessionLength * 60;

let running = false;

$("#session-increment").click(function() {
  sessionLength++;
  seconds = sessionLength * 60;
  $("#session-length").text(sessionLength);
  $("#time-left").text(seconds / 60 + ":00");
});

$("#session-decrement").click(function() {
  sessionLength--;
  $("#session-length").text(sessionLength);

  if (sessionLength < 0) {
    sessionLength *= 0;
  }
  if (sessionLength == -1) {
    sessionLength = 0;
  }
  seconds = sessionLength * 60;
  $("#time-left").text(seconds / 60 + ":00");
});
$("#time-left").text(seconds / 60 + ":00");

function format(secs) {
  return new Date(secs * 1000).toISOString().substring(14, 19);
}

function breakTimer() {
  $("#timer-label").text("Break:");
  seconds = breakLength * 60;
  if (running === false) {
    running = true;
  } else {
    running = false;
  }

  let g = setInterval(function() {
    if (running) {
      seconds--;
      $("#time-left").text(format(seconds));
    } else {
      clearInterval(g);
    }

    if (seconds === 0) {
      reset();
    }
  }, 1);
}

function timer() {
  if (running === false) {
    running = true;
  } else {
    running = false;
  }

  let i = setInterval(function() {
    if (running) {
      seconds--;
      $("#time-left").text(format(seconds));
    } else {
      clearInterval(i);
    }

    if (seconds === 0) {
      breakTimer();
    }
  }, 1);
}

function reset() {
  sessionLength = 25;
  breakLength = 5;
  seconds = sessionLength * 60;
  $("#session-length").text(sessionLength);
  $("#break-length").text(breakLength);
}

$("#start_stop").click(timer);

$("#reset").click(reset);
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>25 + 5 Clock</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="break-label">Break Length:</p>

  <button id="break-increment">↑</button>
  <p id="break-length">5</p>
  <button id="break-decrement">↓
  </button>

  <p id="session-label">Session Length:</p>
  <button id="session-increment">↑</button>
  <p id="session-length">25</p>
  <button id="session-decrement">↓
  </button>

  <p id="timer-label">Session:</p>
  <h1 id="time-left">25:00</h1>

  <button id="start_stop">Play/Pause</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE**: This Pomodoro is for *freeCodeCamp* so try not to alter the test cases for it. One other thing is that also a lot of people use React, although I'm not for this challenge.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure that `running` is `false` before you call `breakTimer()` and make sure to set `running` to `false` in `reset()`

Answer (score 0):

You have not reset the interval.

Define the variable for interval outside start function.

During start, setInterval to its value,
During reset, set it to null.

Comment: [Here's](https://codepen.io/nikhilharry/pen/zYpQNVg) my CodePen. It's stuck in an infinite loop after trying what you said. How could I fix this loop?